# How do you compute $\det(A^3)$ and $\det(2B)$ with $3 \times 3$ invertible matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A, B$ and $C$ are invertible $3 \times 3$ matrices with $\det A = -5$ and $\det B = -4.$ Compute the following.

a) $\det(A^3)$
b) $\det (2B)$
c) $\det (CA^2C^{-1})$

How do you compute the following? I solve the rest but couldn't solve these. Thank you

Comment: for a) det(a^3)=det(a*a*a). From here it should be obvious what do, and for B. det(2B) is just 2*det(B) since 2 is a constant. for c) its similar to part a).

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

- a) What is the $\det (AB)$?
- b) How do you distribute $c \times \det (A)$?
- c) What is the det of the inverse and see first hint

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$ \det (AB)=\det (A) \det(B)$$Also note that if you multiply one row of a matrix by a scalar, then the new determinant is obtained by multiplying the old determinant by the same scalar.